# LLVM IR for loop

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm using LLVM C++ api to generate LLVM IR and using JIT to run the function. 
The function I want to simulate is

```c
double foofor(double a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a += 2;
    }
    return a;
}
```

The corresponding llvm IR code I generate is (using TheFunction->print)

```
define double @foofor(double %a) {
entry:
  br label %loop

loop:                                             ; preds = %loop, %entry
  %a1 = phi double [ 0.000000e+00, %entry ], [ %nextvar, %loop ]
  %addtmp = fadd double %a, 2.000000e+00
  %nextvar = fadd double 1.000000e+00, %a1
  %cmptmp = fcmp ult double %a1, 1.000000e+01
  br i1 %cmptmp, label %loop, label %afterloop

afterloop:                                        ; preds = %loop
  ret double %addtmp
}
```

When I call `foofor(40)`, I get 42 not 60(40 + 20).

The code I have write(without AST)

```
#include "./llvm-8.0.1.src/examples/Kaleidoscope/include/KaleidoscopeJIT.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/APFloat.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Constants.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Type.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Verifier.h"
#include "llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h"
#include "llvm/Target/TargetMachine.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/InstCombine/InstCombine.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/Scalar.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/Scalar/GVN.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace llvm;
using namespace llvm::orc;

//LLVM items
static LLVMContext TheContext;
static IRBuilder<> Builder(TheContext);
static std::unique_ptr<Module> TheModule;
//JIT
static std::unique_ptr<KaleidoscopeJIT> TheJIT;



/*
 *double foofor(double a)
 *{
 *    for(i = 0; i < a; i++) {
 *      a = a + 1
 *    }
 *    return a
 *}
 *
*/
int main()
{
    InitializeNativeTarget();
    InitializeNativeTargetAsmPrinter();

    //init module
    TheModule = llvm::make_unique<Module>("myjit", TheContext);

    //used to be runned by jit later
    TheJIT = llvm::make_unique<KaleidoscopeJIT>();
    TheModule->setDataLayout(TheJIT->getTargetMachine().createDataLayout());

    //define the args
    vector<std::string> ArgNames;

    //foocfor has 1 args
    ArgNames.push_back(string("a"));

    //make the 1 args attach to LLVM Type::double
    std::vector<Type *> Doubles(ArgNames.size(), Type::getDoubleTy(TheContext));

    //generate llvm function type
    FunctionType *FT = FunctionType::get(Type::getDoubleTy(TheContext), Doubles, false);

    //Create function whose FunctionType is FT
    Function *TheFunction = Function::Create(FT, Function::ExternalLinkage, "foofor", TheModule.get());

    //give the name for Function args and save the args in innerargs
    unsigned Idx = 0;

    std::vector<Value *>innerargs;

    for (auto &Arg : TheFunction->args()) {
        Arg.setName(ArgNames[Idx++]);
        innerargs.push_back(&Arg);
    }

    //this function's basic block
    BasicBlock *BB = BasicBlock::Create(TheContext, "entry", TheFunction);

    //create the loop BasicBlock
    BasicBlock *LoopBB = BasicBlock::Create(TheContext, "loop", TheFunction);

    //exit the block
    BasicBlock *AfterBB = BasicBlock::Create(TheContext, "afterloop", TheFunction);

    Builder.SetInsertPoint(BB);
    //add goto LoopBB  in BB
    Builder.CreateBr(LoopBB);


    //start with LoopBB
    Builder.SetInsertPoint(LoopBB);

    //start with 0
    Value *StartVal = ConstantFP::get(TheContext, APFloat(0.0));
    //step is 1
    Value *StepVal = ConstantFP::get(TheContext, APFloat(1.0));

    //local Variable which name is a
    PHINode *Variable = Builder.CreatePHI(Type::getDoubleTy(TheContext), 1, "a");
    //if it's from start block, set Variable 0
    Variable->addIncoming(StartVal, BB);

    //do the body then do cond
    //emit loop body in LoopBB
    //body: arg_a += 1
    Value *ret = Builder.CreateFAdd(innerargs[0], ConstantFP::get(TheContext, APFloat(2.0)), "addtmp");


    //do the cond,if Variable >= 10 then break(goto AfterBB)
    Value *NextVar = Builder.CreateFAdd(StepVal, Variable, "nextvar");

    //if Variable < 10 then goto LoopBB or gotot AfterBB
    Value *cond = Builder.CreateFCmpULT(Variable, ConstantFP::get(TheContext, APFloat(10.0)),  "cmptmp");
    Builder.CreateCondBr(cond, LoopBB, AfterBB);

    Builder.SetInsertPoint(AfterBB);
    Variable->addIncoming(NextVar, LoopBB);

    Builder.CreateRet(ret);

    TheFunction->print(errs());

    //using jit to run this code
    auto H = TheJIT->addModule(std::move(TheModule));
    auto ExprSymbol = TheJIT->findSymbol("foofor");
    double (*foofor)(double) = (double (*)(double))(intptr_t)cantFail(ExprSymbol.getAddress());
    cout <<foofor(40)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: %addtmp = fadd double %a, 2.000000e+00 it will calculate same result.

Comment: @ChiragPatel You are right. Do you  know how to use LLVM c++ api to simulate `a = a + 1`?

Comment: one way is to use alloca, load and store. for more info, See SSA form in context of LLVM ir.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the LLVM IR form for a variable that increases:

```
define double @foofor(double %a) {
entry:
  br label %loop

loop:                                             ; preds = %loop, %entry
  %a1 = phi double [ 0.000000e+00, %entry ], [ %nextvar, %loop ]
  %a2 = phi double [ 0.000000e+00, %a ], [ %addtmp, %loop ]
  %addtmp = fadd double %a2, 2.000000e+00
  %nextvar = fadd double 1.000000e+00, %a1
  %cmptmp = fcmp ult double %a1, 1.000000e+01
  br i1 %cmptmp, label %loop, label %afterloop

afterloop:                                        ; preds = %loop
  ret double %addtmp
}
```

`%a1`/`%nextvar` ought to be ints as well, not doubles, but I left that since that's not the subject of your question.